# Long press gesture in apple watch?

Tags: apple-watch, gesture-recognition

In my apple watch extension i want to use long press gesture functionality. Is there any api equivalent to UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Here my requirement is, on watch extension i have table want to make long press on cell then that cell value should show into Glance.

I found new force touch gesture in apple watch is it similar for my requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You can only open up a menu using Force Touch. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Menus.html).

Comment: menu thing i also gone through it...thank you @vomako

Answer (score 2):

Long press in not supported in WatchKit yet.

The alternative way is the new Force Touch technology. Instead of long press, tell users to press firmly on the screen. You can easily set up a context menu to show to user at that time, and you can associate actions with it easily.

To add a context menu, do the followings:

1. Open the storyboard.
2. Drag a menu object from the library and add it to **Interface Controller** scene.
3. Drag up to three more items. Alternatively you can use this method:

Swift:

```
addMenuItemWithImage([Image], title:[Title], action:[Action])
```

Or:

```
addMenuItemWithImageNamed([Image Name], title:[Title], action:[Action])
```

Objective-C:

```
addMenuItemWithImage:title:action:
```

Or:

```
addMenuItemWithImageNamed:title:action:
```

4. Use Attributes inspector in Xcode for each item to set title and image.
5. Connect each one to an action method in your interface controller class, as the following:

Swift:

```
@IBAction func doMenuItemAction() {}
```

Objective-C:

```
-(IBAction)doMenuItemAction {}
```

6. Save the file.